# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\GPUpdate.xlsx'. only in IE ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have been getting this issue only in IE, any idea as to why. All works fine on my local machine and in Chrome, but IE doesn't. The web MVC app basically uploads user file to server location specified. The application is hosted in IIS 8.5. I have given the user account running the app pool access to the specified folder as well.

Please see code below.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {



                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var targetPath = Server.MapPath("/upload");
                if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName));
                }
                else
                {

                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName));    
                }
```

Any ideas what the issue could be.

I have added the view code below.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table style="margin-top:150px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="file"> Filename</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,.xlsm" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadbutton" onclick="showProgressLoadingSpinner()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
}
```

Comment: Try a different folder other than  'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\GPUpdate.xlsx' - This path is specific to you or the user profile logged in. It may work during development because IIS uses your user name for the app pool. Try something like C:\Uploads.

Comment: What does Server.MapPath("/upload") resolve to?

Comment: @EddiePaz The path 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\FileName.xlsx' is where the user trying to upload may have saved their file, I am not sure where each user will save their file, it could be anywhere on their local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
var targetPath = Server.MapPath("/upload");
```

to

```
var targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");
```

Comment: I have tried changing that but still no luck. This issue is only picked up in IE. The version is 11

Comment: can you show how you set the file parameter when calling the method?

Comment: It doesn´t quite show what the filename value is when entering the method, but it seems it might be that you are sending the filename with an extension and IE doesn´t like it

Try sending the filename without file extension and see if IE likes it better that way, and if it works, handle the filename differently depending on the browser